# R - Dealing with zeros in radomized subsamples

Tags: r, r-factor

I've run into a little problem, simulating the throw of dice. Basically im doing this to get familiar with loops and their output. 
Intention is to simulate the throw of two dice as follows:

```
R = 100
d6 = c(1:6)
d = 60
DICE = NULL
for (i in 1:R)
{
i <- as.factor((sample(d6, size=d, replace = T)) + (sample(d6, size=d, replace = T)))
j <- summary(i)
DICE = rbind(DICE, j)
}
head(DICE)
HIS = colMeans(DICE)
boxplot(DICE)
title(main= "Result 2d6", ylab= "Throws", xlab="")
relHIS = (HIS / sum(HIS))*100
relHIS
```

Problems occur if the result in one cathegorie is 0 (result did not occur in the sample). If this happens randomly in the first subsample one or more the categories (numbers 2-12) are missing. This causes problems ("number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)") in the following subsamples. 
Im sure there is a really simple solution for this, by defining everything beforehand...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some fixes:

```
R = 100
d6 = c(1:6)
d = 60
DICE = matrix(nrow = R, ncol = 11) #pre-allocate
colnames(DICE) <- 2:12 

for (i in 1:R)
{
  sim <- ordered((sample(d6, size=d, replace = T)) + (sample(d6, size=d, replace = T)), 
                 levels = 2:12) #define the factor levels
  sumsim <- table(sim)
  DICE[i,] <- sumsim #sub-assign
}
head(DICE)
HIS = colMeans(DICE)
boxplot(DICE)
title(main= "Result 2d6", ylab= "Throws", xlab="")

prop.table(HIS) * 100
```

Always pre-allocate your result data structure. Growing it in a loop is terribly slow and you know how big it needs to be. Also, don't use the same symbol for the iteration variable and something else.

Answer (score 0):

Omit `as.factor()`in your seventh row

Comment: Have you even looked at the result that would produce?

Comment: Integers, numbers between 2 and 12. Then, when doing the boxplot they should be considered "as factors".

Comment: Look at what `summary` produces for numeric input.

Comment: Do you mean the fact that some values for quartiles are not integers?

Comment: They are not interested in quartiles. Run the code in my answer and look at the resulting graph.